# Solr Realtime Get RemoteSolrException: Expected mime type application/xml but got text/html

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

Solr version on remote server: `solr-4.3.1`
I am trying to use Solr [Realtime Get](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/RealTimeGet) to retrieve document before commit. My code

```
class Test3
{    
  static main(args) 
  {
    def test = new Test3()
    test.run()
  }

  private run() 
  {
    String url = "DEV_SERVER:8983/solr/emr"

    HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer(url)

    SolrQuery q = new SolrQuery();
    q.setRequestHandler("/get");
    q.set("rid", "6662c0f2.ee6a64fe.588j6qohe.9kd087u.0r00dg.6kr5pc2as0qu9m4ibr7f7");

    QueryRequest req = new QueryRequest(q);
    req.setResponseParser(new BinraryResponseParser());

    println "=============================================="
    rsp = req.process(solr);    // ERROR
  }    
}
```

The error stacktrace is:

```
Caught: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got
text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/emr/get. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

</body>
</html>

org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/htm
l. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/emr/get. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

</body>
</html>

        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:459)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:199)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:91)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest$process.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.att.songtao.test.Test3.run(Test3.groovy:48)
        at com.att.songtao.test.Test3.this$2$run(Test3.groovy)
        at com.att.songtao.test.Test3$this$2$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.att.songtao.test.Test3.main(Test3.groovy:14)
```

I am following [Realtime Get](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/RealTimeGet) document and added `updateLog` to `updateHandler` in `solrconfig.xml`. My localhost `"localhost:8983/solr/collection1"` (version `solr-4.7.2`) Realtime Get works perfect, but having it on remote server throws out the above error.

Anyone could provide the insight?

Thanks,

Comment: what is "DEV_SERVER"

Answer (score 2):

This kind of error generally comes , if your configuration file which provides collection name or Solr URL you specified is not correct. In my case, my property file is missing the property for the collection i am searching for.

Comment: This answer helped me.
I was using a base URL without specifying the core/collection name.
It just worked when I added "/coreName" to my base URL

Comment: the mime type error is misleading. The main error is 404 -> not found. I had the same issue when calling solrjClient.commit(...) without specifying the collection. After specifying the collection (=core) it was working. I was using Solr 8.9.0 .

Answer (score 0):

You got a 404 back. Looks like you don't have the ReplicationHandler enabled. You could add this to the solrconfig.xml file and see if the problem goes away

```
<requestHandler name="/get" class="solr.RealTimeGetHandler"> 
     <lst name="defaults"> 
       <str name="omitHeader">true</str> 
       <str name="wt">json</str> 
       <str name="indent">true</str> 
     </lst> 
</requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may be due to Server connectivity.Which server you installed in your system means Tomcat or Jetty and other.

Basically your server is not configure properly and refused your connection when you are trying to search index over Solr.

Verify your Server connection:

For Tomcat execute given statement-

http://Your_Ip:8080/solr

And,Verify which server you are using if you get server connection failed.